# Conveying a dynamic sized array to AWX for use in an ansible playbook

Tags: arrays, variables, ansible

I am currently working on a project as part of an interneship in an IT company and I've been making some good progress as I have had zero knowledge of any of this beforehand.

Quick summary, I have built a PHP based widget for a wordpress page which collects data from the company's cloudboard API to list a certain set of clouds that a user owns.

These clouds run Windows and have multiple user accounts - but it's a variable amount of users that could be just one, or it could be 50 even.

Now my goal ist to create an ansible playbook that is being executed via AWX that disables all users - except the administrator - on that one machine.

As I am getting my data from an API, I have access to the usernames which is suffice to disable them - my problem however is, since the amount of potential users varies, I have no clue on how to set up AWX to ingest my variable amount of usernames that I give to the script via an API call on AWX's API.

With a fixed amount this is my current approach:

This is the AWX Variables part of the Job Template

```
users_to_disable:
  - user1
  - user2
  - user3
```

This is my playbook: (ignore hosts: all, this is purely a local testing environment)

```
---
- name: Disable Windows user accounts on Hyper-V VM
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Disable user account
    win_user:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      account_disabled: true
    loop: "{{ users_to_disable }}"
```

This does work fine and it disables the 3 set up users.

Now I am sending my usernames to the script via the built-in API that comes with AWX as a payload int the API call of the playbook I want to run. But neither how to give it an array, nor how to set the variables part of AWX to have it be an array - especially a dynamic one that differs in size - I can wrap my head around.

This is potentially super easy and I am just not seeing it, but any help would be greatly appreciated.